# Svn to Git of only one subdirectory

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I know about git-svn and have used it to migrate SVN repositories into Git.

With one repo I have a specific requirement, which I can't find a solution for.  That SVN repo contains multiple actual projects as subdirectories:

```
trunk/
    project1/
    project2/
    project3/
branches/
    branch1/
        project1/
        project3/
        project2/
...
```

and so on...

What I want to do is import each of these "sub-projects" in its own repo in git - obviously, keeping revision history, branches, commit messages, tags, etc.

I can use `--ignore-paths` and `--include-paths` switches to only pull one of these sub-projects at a time, but they will still appear under the respective `project1`, etc. subdirectories.  What I really want to end up with is the content of `project` being in the root in each branch (including trunk).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution.  It's not as simple as `git svn clone`, but not too difficult.  So, here's what I did (say, for `project1` in the scenario from the question):

1. Create an empty repo on the git server for `project1`
2. Clone the empty repo onto my local machine:
   `git clone git@git.server.com:group/project1.git`
3. Go into that empty repo working directory:
   `cd project1`
4. Init git svn repo:
   `git svn init --stdlayout --no-metadata https://svn.server.com/group`
5. Now, here's where the magic comes.  If at this point I run `git config --local --list`, I get the following (only relevant lines shown):

   ```
   svn-remote.svn.fetch=trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   svn-remote.svn.branches=branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
   svn-remote.svn.tags=tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
   ```

   All that I need to do now is `git config --local --edit` and add `project1` in the correct places:

   ```
   svn-remote.svn.fetch=trunk/project1:refs/remotes/trunk
   svn-remote.svn.branches=branches/*/project1:refs/remotes/branches/*
   svn-remote.svn.tags=tags/*/project1:refs/remotes/tags/*
   ```
6. Now you can `git svn fetch`
7. Set branches and tags:

   ```
   for branch in `git branch -r | grep "branches/" | sed 's/ branches\///'`; do
       git branch $branch refs/remotes/branches/$branch
   done

   for tag in `git branch -r | grep "tags/" | sed 's/ tags\///'`; do
       git tag -a -m"Converting SVN tags" $tag refs/remotes/tags/$tag
   done
   ```
8. And finally push it all to the remote:

   ```
   git push --all origin
   git push --tags origin
   ```

Now if you clone your repo, you'll get the content of `project1` in the root of your cloned repo - exactly what I was looking for.